# Сохранения значения select при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript

Есть у меня такой `select box`

```
<div class="select-outer">
    <select name="sel" onchange="fn()" id="block_time">
      <option selected name="0">city1</option>
      <option name="1">city2</option>
      <option name="2">city3</option>
      <option name="3">city4</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Делаю сохранение выбора после перезагрузки страницы, опшн выбирается но значение не задается) помогите исправить.

Вот такой JS скрипт для сохранения значения, если и в JQ есть решение по проще буду рад взять на вооружение)

```
<script>
function getCookie(name) {
    var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
        "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
    ))
    return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined
}
function setCookie(name, value, props) {
    props = props || {}
    var exp = props.expires
    if (typeof exp == "number" && exp) {
        var d = new Date()
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + exp * 1000)
        exp = props.expires = d
    }
    if (exp && exp.toUTCString) {
        props.expires = exp.toUTCString()
    }

    value = encodeURIComponent(value)
    var updatedCookie = name + "=" + value
    for (var propName in props) {
        updatedCookie += "; " + propName
        var propValue = props[propName]
        if (propValue !== true) {
            updatedCookie += "=" + propValue
        }
    }
    document.cookie = updatedCookie

}

function fn() {
    var elem = document.getElementsByName('sel')[0]
    var currentOptionIndex = elem.selectedIndex;
    setCookie('OptionIndex', currentOptionIndex);
}


window.onload = function () {
        var elem = document.getElementsByName('sel')[0];
        elem.selectedIndex = getCookie('OptionIndex') || 1;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Что за значение, которое не задается?

Comment: У меня таймер настроен под этот select box, когда выбираешь город с таймера минусуется кол-во заданных минут.
`var cities = ['city1', 'ciity2','city3','city4'];
var shifts = [0,-5,-5,-7]; `
вот такой ассоц. массив который знанчение которых задаются полем `name`

Comment: При установке свойства программно событие изменения не вызывается. Вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Да, скрипт не выполняет действия)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> При установке свойства программно событие изменения не вызывается. Вы
>   это имеете в виду?
>
> Да, скрипт не выполняет действия)

Попробуйте:

```
elem.fireEvent("onchange");
```

или

```
elem.onchange()
```

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Где именно задать это?

Comment: "При установке свойства программно" По видимому в конце `onload` или в том месте где вы присваиваете `elem.selectedIndex` значение.